# Javascript onclick functions does not seem to work in IE11/Edge/Chrome

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, dom-events

I am moving from IE (older version) to IE11, Edge and Chrome browsers. The Javascript functions working in the older versions does not seem to work with newer versions/browsers.

I tried by calling my own `function()` without passing any arguments something like this

> myFunc() {alert("Hello, you clicked me!!")}

It actually displayed the alert message. But the code that I have in the next section, does not seem to work. Not sure why?

```html
<input name="txtToDate" class="label" maxlength="10" readonly onfocus="blur()"> <A HREF="javascript:doNothing()" onClick="setDateField(txtToDate);  top.newWin = window.open('/html/calendar.html','cal','dependent=yes,width=210,height=230,screenX=200,screenY=300,titlebar=yes')">
```

What is expected of this code is, it should pop-up a date calendar (while `onclick`) to select a date and populate the date to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<input name="txtToDate" class="label" maxlength="10" readonly onfocus="blur()" /> <A href="javascript:void()" onClick="setDateField(txtToDate); top.newWin = window.open('/html/calendar.html','cal','dependent=yes,width=210,height=230,screenX=200,screenY=300,titlebar=yes')"> Link icon or name here</a>
```

Enclosing the anchor tag and the input could help (I guess). If your function is not working properly or not recognizing the "click" event or any other event (or even not working as intended) you can pass an argument to it, for example `onclick="blur(e)"` then handling the argument as the first thing inside that function like `e.preventDefault()` to prevent any undesired beheaviors during the execution of that event.

I hope it helps you in some way. :)